# Calling a controller from another controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, controller

I have two controllers in my AngularJS app. They look like:

```
controller("AppCtrl", function($scope){

    //do some stuff here

})
```

And

```
controller("ChatCtrl", function($scope, chat_service){

    $scope.init = function(){
        chat_service.identify(...nick and some other data...);
        chat_service.on_users_update(function(){...do stuff here...});
    }

    //some other methods

    $scope.init();

})
```

Note that `AppCtrl` is my main controller and it gets executed when you open the app.
The problems is that I want to call `ChatCtrl.init()` from my `AppCtrl`, but I don't know how.

Obviously, `$rootScope.$emit()` and `$rootScope.$on()` won't work as the `$on()` part (which will be in `ChatCtrl`) hasn't been executed yet at the time the ``$emit```` happens.

And I really don't want to do chat-related stuff in `AppCtrl`.

Is there a way to call `init()` from `AppCtrl`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - How to run controllers from other controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405241/angularjs-how-to-run-controllers-from-other-controllers)

Comment: @Stewie you obviously didn't read my question, otherwise you wouldn't have market it as possible duplicate. tip: it isn't.

Comment: How you have implemented seems that the init method gets called when the chartcontroller is initialized. Do you want to call this init method at specific time?

Comment: @Chandermani yes, I want init to be called the very first time I open the app.

Comment: When the controller is not there how is calling anything on it possible. You can extract the config code into a service like `chartConfig`. Inject it into the two controllers. Update it in the App controller, and use it in Chart Controller

Comment: @Chandermani The controller is there. Javascript will first parse everything in my file, then it will start running it (both controllers live in the same file). I really don't want to extract anything from the chat controller, but just make the main controller *call* the chat controller and/or let it know that it should identify itself.

Comment: Not possible. Also the javascript has just parsed you controller definition. It has to be instantiated by the angular framework. The controllers are basically Constructor function, someone needs to call them to create function objects.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to place that in my AppCtrl... :(